# CiviContribute - convert amounts into words

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, tokens

Is there a plugin that would populate a field with a word amount of a contribution total? Using such a token can make a letter more personalized. Similar to the SpellNumber formula in Excel. I.e. $240.00 = two hundred and forty dollars.

Comment: don't think so, but it should not be too difficult to create, here's some info on the php involved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such plugin that I am aware of.